# FontAwesome code automatically getting added to HTML files when using an API or opening files from live server

Tags: javascript, html, css, code-injection

I'm facing an issue where FontAwesome code is automatically getting added to my HTML files whenever I use an API or open files from the live server. Below is an example of the unwanted code that is being inserted into my files:
`NOW https://fontawesome.com/license/free (Icons: CC BY 4.0, Fonts: SIL OFL 1.1, Code: MIT License) * Copyright 2023 Fonticons, Inc. */@font-face{font-family:"FontAwesome";font-display:block;src:url(https://ka-f.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/webfonts/free-fa-solid-900.woff2) format("woff2"),url(https://ka-f.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/webfonts/free-fa-solid-900.ttf) format("truetype")}@font-face{font-family:"FontAwesome";font-display:block;src:url(https://ka-f.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/webfonts/free-fa-brands-400.woff2) format("woff2"),url(https://ka-f.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/webfonts/free-fa-brands-400.ttf) format("truetype")}@font-face{font-family:"FontAwesome";font-display:block;src:url(https://ka-f.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/webfonts/free-fa-regular-400.woff2) format("woff2"),url(https://ka-f.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/webfonts/free-fa-regular-400.ttf) format("truetype");unicode-range:u+f003,u+f006,u+f014,u+f016-f017,u+f01a-f01b,u+f01d,u+f022,u+f03e,u+f044,u+f046,u+f05c-f05d,u+f06e,u+f070,u+f087-f088,u+f08a,u+f094,u+f096-f097,u+f09d,u+f0a0,u+f0a2,u+f0a4-f0a7,u+f0c5,u+f0c7,u+f0e5-f0e6,u+f0eb,u+f0f6-f0f8,u+f10c,u+f114-f115,u+f118-f11a,u+f11c-f11d,u+f133,u+f147,u+f14e,u+f150-f152,u+f185-f186,u+f18e,u+f190-f192,u+f196,u+f1c1-f1c9,u+f1d9,u+f1db,u+f1e3,u+f1ea,u+f1f7,u+f1f9,u+f20a,u+f247-f248,u+f24a,u+f24d,u+f255-f25`

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

I haven't intentionally created or implemented any of this code, and it keeps happening whenever I insert an API or open a file from the live server. I'm not sure why this is occurring. Can anyone help me understand and resolve this issue?

Comment: You'll need to give us some more info about how your system actually works. And explain what stuff like _"whenever I insert an API"_ actually means.

Comment: If I, for example, insert the react cdn or i use the chatgpt api,on the backend,it shows em the origin code of the APi,wheN I didn't did that